# JMock tutorial using JUnit 3?

Tags: java, jmock, junit3

I'm looking for a JMock tutorial using JUnit 3.

Preferably an easy one as well. Every JMock tutorial I have found has been fairly difficult to read through.

Also, is it worth it to use JUnit 4?

Thanks

Comment: Just found this one: http://jeantessier.com/SoftwareEngineering/Mocking.html#jMock

From this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905157/how-to-get-started-with-testingjmock

Answer (score 1):

Note that jmock has changed a lot in the version that goes with JUnit 4.  I recommend using JUnit 4 and the latest JMock when writing new tests rather than investing time learning something that doesn't have a future path.

The later version of JMock makes things easier by integrating with the JUnit lifecycle as a runner.